# convert the yaw Euler angle into into the range [0 , 360]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I used the following code to get the yaw Euler angle:

```
// Convert quaternion to RPY.
  tf::Quaternion q;
  tf::quaternionMsgToTF(imu_msg->orientation, q);
  tf::Matrix3x3(q).getRPY(roll, pitch, yaw);
```

I get the Euler angle varying from [0,PI] and [-PI, 0]

I need rotation angles in the range of 0 to 360. Is it possible to get that directly?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/141366/convert-the-yaw-euler-angle-into-into-the-range-%5B0-,-360%5D./) by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-03-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can't get angles in degrees directly from the available library calls, but it's pretty trivial to convert radians to degrees:

```
double yaw = ...; // however you want to get yaw.
double yaw_degrees = yaw * 180.0 / M_PI; // conversion to degrees
if( yaw_degrees < 0 ) yaw_degrees += 360.0; // convert negative to positive angles
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2014-03-18**:
nice very thanks

**Comment by [vschmidt](https://answers.ros.org/users/25950/vschmidt/) on 2017-12-03**:
This answer was some time ago, but is this not incorrect?

[PEP 103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) specifies that yaw measured from the x-axis (i.e. in a geographic frame from East) and is positive CCW. Heading of course is measured from the y-axis, positive CW.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try the [angles](http://wiki.ros.org/angles) package which provides C++ api calls for angle normalization, conversions between radians and degrees, and finding minimum angular distance.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2014-03-18**:
thanks for your answer, please can you tell me how to use the  angles package? I am not succeed.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-03-19**:
Without more info about how you are not succeeding, it's hard to help.  You need to (1) include angles in your manifest.xml or package.xml (2) #include <angles/angles.h> (3) Run code like "yaw = angles::to_degrees(angles::normalize_angle_positive(yaw));"

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-03-19**:
Sorry for the bad formatting of point (2).... not my fault.  See [bug report](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues/65)

**Comment by [underwater](https://answers.ros.org/users/1303/underwater/) on 2014-04-01**:
very thanks